# How can we receive the url into wso2 esb proxy service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-stratos, wso2-esb

My aim is i have to receive the url's like www.google.com from client  in proxy service and send response back to client.

How can i solve this.Here i am sending my proxy service.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
      name="Geturl"
      transports="https http"
      startOnLoad="true"
      trace="enable"
      statistics="enable">
  <description/>
  <target>
     <inSequence onError="fault">
        <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property name="REQUEST_HOST_HEADER" value="www.google.com" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="querystrings"
                  expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')"/>
        <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"
                  expression="get-property('REQUEST_HOST_HEADER')"
                  scope="axis2"
                  type="STRING"/>
        <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="GET" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
        <header name="To"
                expression="get-property('www.google.com')"/>
<property name="message" value="Response message"/>
<property name="Sender Address" expression="get-property('www.google.com')"/>
        <log level="full"/>
        <log level="full">
           <property name="REQUEST_HOST_HEADER" value="www.wso2.org"/>
        </log>
        <send/>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence onError="fault">
        <log level="full"/>
        <log level="full">
           <property name="REQUEST_HOST_HEADER" value="www.google.com"/>
        </log>
        <log level="full">
           <property name="success" value="success"/>
        </log>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use the WSO2 ESB as a proxy to route web traffic from a client?

Answer (score 0):

In the outSequence of a proxy service, when you call `<send/>` , the response will be sent back to the client. Try sample proxy service [1], and invoke using Try-It or SOAP UI. You will see that the response comming to the client.

[1]http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Sample+150%3A+Introduction+to+Proxy+Services

Comment: Thank you Lakmali, it's working ,but if my url conains some data like www.w3schools.com , how can i receive this data into my service and send response to some other client.